# How to use generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I wont to use only one method to unbox like this:

```
public interface IModule<T, U>
  where T : BaseBox
  where U : BaseItem
{
  U[] GetItems<T>( int id );
}

public sealed partial class Module<T, U> : IModule<T, U>
  where T : BaseBox
  where U : BaseItem
{
  U[] IModule<T, U>.GetItems<T>( int id )
  {
    return T.Unboxing(); // It is wrong!
  }
}
```

But I can't. How do I have to write right generics?

Next code to understand.I have item's types:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
  protected int _id;
  protected string _description;
}

public sealed class TriangleItem : BaseItem
{
  public int TriangleId { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
  public string TriangleDescription { get { return _description; } set { _description = value; } }
  public Color color { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CircleItem : BaseItem
{
  public int CircleId { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; } }
  public string CircleDescription { get { return _description; } set { _description = value; } }
  public int Radius { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have boxes for items:

```
public abstract class BaseBox
{
  public string ItemsXml { get; set; }
  public abstract BaseItem[] Unboxing();
}

public sealed class TriangleBox : BaseBox
{
  public TriangleItem[] Unboxing()
  {
    return Util.FromXml( ItemsXml ).Select( i => new TriangleItem { TriangleId = int.Parse( i ), TriangleDescription = i, Color = Color.Red } ).ToArray();
  }
}

public sealed class CircleBox : BaseBox
{
  public CircleItem[] Unboxing()
  {
    return Util.FromXml( ItemsXml ).Select( i => new CircleItem { CircleId = int.Parse( i ), CircleDescription = i, Radius = 5 } ).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Here I have different implementations Unboxing-method.

Comment: You have written `T.Unboxing()` as though it is a static method, you need an instance to use

Comment: You'll either need to ask for the correct `T` as argument, or use your `int id` to get it.

Comment: I really think you should drop generics and try to do pure OOP design. Generics in C# are not as powerful as other generic-based languages, like Haskell. Abusing generics like that is only asking for problems.

Answer (score 3):

As [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse) mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397205/how-to-use-generic#comment27019918_18397205), you are trying to use T as a static method and need an instance. For example,

```
public sealed partial class Module<T, U> : IModule<T, U>
  where T : BaseBox
  where U : BaseItem
{
    private T _box;

    public Module(T box)
    {
        _box = box;
    }

    U[] IModule<T, U>.GetItems<T>( int id )
    {
        // You need to determine how id relates to _box.
        return _box.Unboxing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, didn't have time to completely write and check an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all coming to your interface definition:

```
public interface IModule<T, U>
  where T : BaseBox
  where U : BaseItem
{
  U[] GetItems<T>( int id );
}
```

You can simply declare `GetItems<T>(int id)` as `GetItems(int id)`.

Your code `return T.Unboxing()` is wrong because `T` represents a type (For e.g. the classes `TriangleBox`, `CircleBox` etc.) and not the object you want to call your method on.
You can fix this either by taking the particular object as a parameter in `GetItems` or by taking the `BaseBox T` as a constructor argument. i.e.
either

```
U[] IModule<T, U>.GetItems(T box, int id )
    {
      return box.Unboxing(); // I don't know what you plan to do with id
    }
```

or

```
private readonly T _box;
public Module(T box)
    {
       _box = box;
    }

U[] IModule<T, U>.GetItems(int id )
    {
       return _box.Unboxing(); // I don't know what you plan to do with id
    }
```